# Is possible to lock screen in browser on mobile devices?

Tags: jquery-mobile

At the moment i am developing a small web application which is based on swipe and for example when i swipe it to right on my iPad or iPod the screen also goes to right. Is it possible somehow to lock screen?

Answer (score 0):

You could download the jquery Dialog plug-in, http://jqueryui.com/dialog/ and set a condition for it to pop up, and also a message stating that the screen is currently locked.  This is probably one of the cleanest ways of controlling your screen in regards to users proceeding or staying.